# React Popup does not access update state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events, react-popper

I am using `react-popup`. I have problem when I want to access update state value it not working . Mean, it not rendering UI if state is changed . When I closed pop up form then I clicked again then UI was reflected . I want if state is changed then I want to re-render UI Immediately , I don't want to form closed and re-open for new changes.

I am using this lib : http://minutemailer.github.io/react-popup/

Full Component Code : https://jsfiddle.net/m4fwvxk2/

**Code**

```
     Popup.create({
      title: popupTitle,
      content: (
        <div>
         <select
            name="taskType"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="browser-default custom-select marginArea"
          >
            <option value="no">Task Type</option>
            <option value="meeting">Meeting</option>
            <option value="followUp">Follow Up</option>
            <option value="viewing">Viewing</option>
            <option value="reminder">Reminder</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
          {this.state.isCustomer ? <p>Hello</p> : null}
       </div>
)})
```

As you see I am trying to access `this.state.isCustomer` update value on base of update value I want to set some condition but I am not able to achieve my goal could someone please help me how to solve this problem .

Comment: What part of the code changes the isCustomer field in state?

Comment: Yes, actually I want to access `isCustomer` updated state value but `Popup.create` method does not allow me to access when I console `isCustomer` value in render method it show me update value . Now I want to access it in `Popup.create` method it not reflect the updated value

Comment: @MaartenDev could you please help me I really need to fix this issue

Comment: Could you point to the documentation where the `Popup.create` method is documented? You are using: https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper

Comment: @MaartenDev I am using this lib http://minutemailer.github.io/react-popup/

Comment: It seems that the content in the popup does not get updated, i suggest using another library because this one seems quite limited and has poor docs. @jonasprop

Comment: We can't see from that code snippet when `Popup.create` is being called nor the scope it's in. Also, you should note that `this.state.isCustomer` is evaluated when `Popup.create` is called and it will always be the same value for that instance of the popup.

Comment: @Distortum actually I am new to React, I will upload my full component code in `jsfiddle` could you please help me to achieve me goal

Comment: @Distortum please see full component code 
https://jsfiddle.net/m4fwvxk2/

Comment: @MaartenDev please you can also view my code, I need really urgent thanks

Comment: The demo doesn't work, i would suggest looking into other libraries. @jonasprop

Comment: `this.handleChange` updates `this.state.customer`. Your problem is that `this.state.customer` is evaluated as part of calling `Popup.create`, so all you're getting is the old value. It looks like this library wasn't designed to handle this scenario.